# Orthogonal projection - is it iso/mono/epimorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a euclidean space, and $V\subset X$.  Let's denote $P_V: X\to V$ the orthogonal projection on the subspace $V$.
Then:
**a.** For each subspace $V$, $P_V$ is a monomorphism
**b.** For each subspace $V$ $P_V$ is an epimorphism
**c.** For each subspace $V$ $P_V$ is an isomorphism

**My approach:**
**a.**
It is not true,  for example when $\dim V < \dim X$. 
Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2, X=\mathbb{R}^3$.
$P_V([1,2,5]) = [a,b]=P_V([1,2,9])$, so it is not monomorphism, because altough $[1,2,5]\neq [1,2,9]$ we have $P_V([1,2,5])=P_V([1,2,9])$.

**c.** From **a.** we can see that it is also false.

**b.**  It is true because:
Let $n=\dim X, m=\dim V$, $e_1,...,e_n$ will be orthonormal base of $X$.
$\forall_{k=1...m}\ \ P_V(e_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \langle e_k, e_i\rangle e_i = e_k$
Therefore the system of vectors $P_V(e_1),...,P_V(e_m)$  is base of $V$, hence $P_V$ is isomorphism.

I ask for checking my answers, but first for checking of all my explanations.

Comment: The answer is correct. Now, in (a): I'm guessing you meant $\;V=\{(x,y,0)\}\;$, right? Because there are infinite copies of $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ in $ \;\Bbb R^3\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are correct.

However, the reason for **a** is wrong: you cannot consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Better, consider $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V=\langle e_1\rangle$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $P_V(e_2)=0$, so $P_V$ is not injective. Or you can consider $V=\{0\}$.

For **b**, just consider that, for every $v\in V$, $P_V(v)=v$. However, you can only state $P_V$ is surjective (or an epimorphism, if you prefer this terminology), not an isomorphism.

---

As an aside, you can also note that $P_V$ is an isomorphism if and only if $V=X$.

Comment: when in comes to **a.** - no isomorphism due to $P_V(0) = P_V(e_1)$ ?

Comment: If my solution for **b.** is not correct ?

Comment: @HaskellFun No, I didn't read it carefully: you can't conclude $P_V$ is an isomorphism, but only it is an epimorphism.

Comment: Ok, but: You shown that $P_V(0) = P_V(e_1)$. It is why $P_V$ is not *mono*morphism ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Yes, of course